# how to check is in-app subscription available or not when app open?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, in-app-subscription

I am using [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) package. I want to update of subscription when subscription status changed for logged in user.

snippet :

```
    final purchaseUpdated = iapConnection.purchaseStream;
    _subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen(
      onPurchaseUpdate,
      onDone: _subscription.cancel();,
      onError: _subscription.cancel();,
    );
    
    Future<void> onPurchaseUpdate(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
    for (var purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
      await _handlePurchase(purchaseDetails);
    }
  }
```

Thanks.